# In android how do you manage Intents to be passed only when the app is alive?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-asynctask

I have this activity X which passed some data fetched over the AsyncTask to activity Y. Till the data from AsyncTask is fetched there is a loading progressbar that is made visible till the "doPostMethod" method the AsyncTask is succeeded. Now when this background process of data fetching is carried out, when the user presses the back button of the phone, the app goes to previous activity, but what happens is, the activity X's doPostMethod is getting called which in-turn proceeds to activity Y with the data it has to send. Is there any way to get rid of this bug?

doBackground : fetches result from a remote API call
doPostMethod :

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    loader.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    Intent preSummaryIntent = new Intent(PreSummary.this, SummaryList.class);
    preSummaryIntent.putExtra(SEARCH_RESULTS, result);
    startActivity(preSummaryIntent);
}
```

Comment: please show the code and logcat logs. Thanks.

Comment: Edited my content to add code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use setCancelable(false) for dailog to prevent dismissal of dialog while process not completed. you can cancel you asyn task for doing this override you onBackPressed() in your activity and init check that your asyn task is running or not if running then cancel it by calling  "task.cancel(true)" to cancel asyncTask do somethig like below

```
    @Override
 public void onBackPressed() {
    if(asyncTask != null){
        if(asyncTask.getStatus() == Status.RUNNING){
            asyncTask.cancel(true);
            asyncTask = null;
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: I seriously din't get a clue on what you were trying to say. I accept I am a noob in android dev.

Comment: Hey thanks. But still when the progressdialog is running and i tap on the back button, it closes the progressdialog while it still runs the asynctask in background. it doesn't get cancelled ! :o

Comment: when progress dialog is visible and you tap on back button then dialogs onBackPressed is called not activity's, so you need to set   "setCancelable(false)" for progress dialog. let me know if you still have problem

Comment: Trying that now.. #Update :D

Comment: Thats awesome! user3337034. though I am not able to hit back I at lease prevent the next activity from opening once the asynctask is in progress!

Answer (score 1):

At First you wanna to check your App is running like keep alive or not. then only you have to pass your intent values.

try this code to find your application is Running or not..

```
ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) this.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
List<RunningAppProcessInfo> procInfos = activityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();
for(int i = 0; i < procInfos.size(); i++){
   if(procInfos.get(i).processName.equals("com.me.checkprocess"))
   {
        Log.e("Result", "App is running - Doesn't need to reload");
        break;
   }
   else
   {
        Log.e("Result", "App is not running - Needs to reload);
   }
}
```

or set any boolean variable and then check it to pass your Intent values..

```
Intent i = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
i.putExtra("USER", userData);
Intent i1 = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,Pacs_WakeupService.class);
i1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
i1.putExtra("USER", userData);                      
startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

Bro, it is very simple to test in your PostExecuteMethod();

check my code .... your will really like this bed-logic. I am using a component of activity to test, either the activity i alive or not.

```
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        if (imgageView != null && result != null) {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainMenuActivity.this, SubmitOrderActivity.class));
        }
   }
```

I hope it will work for you :)

Edited:
if you want to stop your async when you will switch the activity

```
@Override
    protected void onPause() {
        if (download != null && download.getStatus() != AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED) {
            download.cancel(true);
        }
        super.onPause();
    }
```

Comment: So this will work only if the result fetched is not null right? But the thing is, dobackground keeps polling the API request till gets a valid response. Once it gets a response it is going to start the next activity.

Comment: The OnPostExecute will only be called when the doBackGround completes its processing and polling API resquests.

Comment: but the problem is, asynctask keeps running even if i hit the back button. i agree that it wouldn't start the activity. but it would still keep using the internet isnt it. ?